Is there any way to reduce the size of a partition that already contains a version 1.2 md array?
I have an 1.2 metadata md array with data that has been extended from smaller sizes to larger and larger.
The current configuration, contains one disk that is larger than the rest of them, and unfortunately when I partitioned this disk, I allocated almost all its available space and added the partition to the array with mdadm --add
Now I'm considering shrinking the partition down to the size of the other md units and create one more partition for copying temporary files or for some other mountpoint, as my OS partition has started filling up too.
I know the simple way to do is to to just fail and remove the partition, shrink it or delete and recreate it with gparted, and then add the smaller partition to the array, but this would cause a full resync (that takes a long long time).
Since the data are already stored in the disk, is there any way to shrink the partition and at the same time let mdadm know that the smaller partition is already part of the existing array, so that it will not resync? (I guess  the missing metadata will not allow me to try to use re-add).
Could I somehow backup the metadata that indicate that the partition is part of the array and put them back on the new smaller partition, without touching the data of the filesystem at the start of the drive?
Thanks for any idea.
